# How to implement this function without an if-else branch? (GLSL)

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I'm working on an game, using `OpenGL ES 2.0`

I would like to eliminate branches in the fragment shader, if possible. But there is a function, which I cannot improve:

```
float HS(in float p, in float c) {

    float ap = abs(p);

    if( ap > (c*1.5) ) {
        return ap - c ;
    } else {
        return mod(ap+0.5*c,c)-0.5*c;
    }

}
```

The `c` is a constant in most of the cases, if it helps in this situation. I use this function like this:

```
vec3 op = sign(p1)*vec3(
    HS(p1.x, cc),
    HS(p1.y, cc),
    HS(p1.z, cc)
);
```

Comment: Do you want to increase the performance of this code, or do you want to remove the condition? Because those are two different things.

Comment: I would like to increase the performance of this code, by removing if-else branches first.

Comment: And what if that's not the most effective way to improve performance here?

Comment: In that case, I'm curious to any kind optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a trick that "eliminates" the branch. But the more important thing it does is vectorize your code. After all, the compiler probably eliminated the branch for you; it's far less likely that it realized it could do this:

```
vec3 HSvec(in vec3 p, in const float c)
{
  vec3 ap = abs(p);
  vec3 side1 = ap - c;
  const float val = 0.5 * c;
  vec3 side2 = mod(ap + val, vec3(c)) - val;

  bvec3 tests = greaterThan(ap, vec3(c*1.5));
  return mix(side2, side1, vec3(tests));
}
```

This eliminates lots of redundant computations, as well as doing lots of computations simultaneously.

The key here is the `mix` function. `mix` performs linear interpolation between the two arguments based on the third. But since a `bool` converted to a `float` will be exactly 1.0 or 0.0, it's really just selecting either `side1` or `side2`. And this selection is defined by the results of the component-wise `greaterThan` operation.

Comment: It works, but the code should be: `lessThan(vec3(c*1.5), ap)`

Comment: @IterAtor: Or `greaterThan`; we have that too.

Comment: I haven't heard about `greaterThan` until now. It is the answer, I was looking for. Could you please give me some hints, how this code should be even more optimized?

Comment: Calling mod() is probably relatively expensive, so if you have a performance problem trying to avoid that would be good. Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code whether that it possible though.